# Generating values knowing the Copula family and the one variable

Tags: r, statistics, predict, estimation

I have a question concerning the Copula method in R. I am analyzing two data sets x (60 values) and y(50 values).

---

I have already analyze this data set, finding the appropriate copula family characterizing their join distribution.

```
library(copula)
library(VineCopula)
library(CDVine)
library(spcopula)

x<-c(36.0,24.0,75.0,34.3,67.0,41.7,33.2,20.7,90.0,50.0,6.0,73.1,97.2,46.5,51.5,39.2,
 62.0,37.4,151.0,88.1,92.6,61.7,61.0,69.8,34.5,55.5,76.6,41.7,121.5,56.2,32.4,41.3,
 15.6,126.6,28.7,14.4,49.9,38.6,23.4,62.2,46.2,20.6,31.6,97.3,4.1,66.3,67.9,92.2,
 35.8,23.0,77.9,15.0,41.1,84.9,37.0,74.5,31.5,46.1,63.6,95.3,132.7)
y<-c(141.0,105.9,175.4,205.8,304.3,129.9,94.2,82.1,512.7,250.4,26.5,215.0,595.3,420.4,277.0,180.1,
 206.1,199.9,662.9,476.6,444.5,330.8,178.5,235.4,105.5,224.4,433.9,160.1,451.7,150.8,43.5,316.5,
 43.4,204.9,112.8,56.6,216.6,279.2,135.1,313.5,125.1,87.4,117.8,164.3,17.8,605.7,677.4,
 422.6,173.3,59.1)

x1<-pobs(x)
y1<-pobs(y)
x2<-x1[1:50]
x3<-x1[51:61]

cor(x2,y1,method = "kendall")
BiCopIndTest(x2,y1)
BiCopSelect(x2, y1, familyset=NA)

# My copula is Clayton with parameter=3.38
# Using Clayton Copula and x3 I want to producw the values of y
```

---

My overall purpose is to produce the rest 10 values for y, knowing the x values (x3) and the copula family.

---

I am slightly confused because I have tried many approaches but I am not convinced about any. 
Could anyone help me? Any code sample would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share example data and code?

Comment: @mtoto thanks for your reply, I reconstruct my question